# How to apply Ito's Lemma to this problem?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales

We have the martingale representation theorem:
$G = E[G]+\int_0^t\theta_sdW_s$

Now, given $G=1_A$, where $A=\{exp(W_t)>K\}$, how to find the corresponding $\theta_t$?

The hint I received was to find $E[G]=P(A)=P(W_t>\ln K)$, then apply Ito's Lemma to the functional form of $E[G]$. And $E[G]$ should be a Gaussian integral. But I'm not sure how to apply Ito's Lemma to this integral.

Comment: $A$ should be an event; what does $exp(W_t<K)$ mean?

Comment: you are right. it's a typo. $A={exp(W_t)>K}$